# How to infer one-to-one/one-to-many relationship?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, natural-language

We have a file with IP addresses patterns as shown below:

```
 source IP    ,,,,,,,    Dest IP

 10.10.1.41   ,,,,,,,  12.13.67.89

 67.34.6.8    ,,,,,,,  34.67.8.90

 10.10.1.41   ,,,,,,,  12.13.67.89

 10.10.1.41   ,,,,,,,  12.13.67.89
```

where `,,,,,,,` represents other IP's.

Based on this table we need to train a NLP engine that can infer the relationship between IPs. For example, it could be another column as below:

```
,,,,,,,    RelationType

,,,,,,,    one to many
,,,,,,,    many to one
,,,,,,,    one to one
```

How can we infer this relationship?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to infer.
It's a relation from the `source IP` column to the `Dest IP` column?

Comment: Your question is poorly worded, try re-writting it, also in a way it's clear what your actual question is.

Comment: we want to infer the relation between 2 IP addresses columns. is it **one to one** or **one to many**   or **many to one** .

Comment: @vijay why you consider this to be a NLP problem? It's more likely a database one.

Comment: Hi lucas, actually if it is trained by NLP engine we can read multiple csv's and infer them in realtime and raise an alert accordingly. pls let me know other way around to solve this problem

Comment: You can merge source IP with  Dest IP and use the solution in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000379/merge-tables-classify-output-according-to-how-rows-where-joined to check if the join was one-to-one, many-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many.   I also think it is more a database issue.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the `mappings` function in the `utilities` package

You can examine functional mappings between variables in a data-frame using the `mappings` function in the [`utilities` package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/utilities/index.html) in `R`.  This function takes an input data-frame and examines whether there are mappings between the variables.  By default the function examines only the factor variables, but you can examine all variables in the data by setting `all.vars = TRUE`.  (Bear in mind that mappings between non-factor variables should be interpreted with caution; continuous variables are almost always in a one-to-one mapping because they do not have duplicate values.)  Here is an example of a mock dataset containing five factor variables, with a number of mappings between them.

```
#Create data frame 
VAR1 <- c(0,1,2,2,0,1,2,0,0,1)
VAR2 <- c('A','B','B','B','A','B','B','A','A','B')
VAR3 <- c(1:10)
VAR4 <- c('A','B','C','D','A','B','D','A','A','B')
VAR5 <- c(1:5,1:5)
DATA <- data.frame(VAR1 = factor(VAR1),
                   VAR2 = factor(VAR2),
                   VAR3 = factor(VAR3),
                   VAR4 = factor(VAR4),
                   VAR5 = factor(VAR5))
DATA

   VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5
1     0    A    1    A    1
2     1    B    2    B    2
3     2    B    3    C    3
4     2    B    4    D    4
5     0    A    5    A    5
6     1    B    6    B    1
7     2    B    7    D    2
8     0    A    8    A    3
9     0    A    9    A    4
10    1    B   10    B    5
```

We can examine the mappings using the `R` code below.  As you can see, the output of the function shows you all the functional relationships that hold between the factors, and it also tells you which factors are "redundant" (i.e., functions of other factors).  By default the output includes a DAG plot showing the mappings between the factors.

```
#Examine mappings in the data
library(utilities)
MAPS <- mappings(DATA)
MAPS


Mapping analysis for data-frame DATA containing 5 factors (analysis ignores NA values) 

There were 7 mappings identified: 
 
     VAR1 → VAR2 
     VAR3 → VAR1 
     VAR3 → VAR2 
     VAR3 → VAR4 
     VAR3 → VAR5 
     VAR4 → VAR1 
     VAR4 → VAR2 

Redundant factors: 
 
     VAR1 
     VAR2 
     VAR4 
     VAR5 

Non-Redundant factors: 
 
     VAR3
```

[image]

As can be seen from the output and the plot, the only non-redundant factor in the data-frame is `VAR3`; all other factor variables are functions of this variable.  (This can aslo be confirmed by looking at the values in the data-frame.)